# How to solve the following error while deploying solution into sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created one list definition in visual studio and trying to deploy into my sharpeoint site. But I am getting the following error.

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Field type
>   boolean is not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to
>   delete this field.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: please post the list definition here so we can have a look

Comment: First debug the code and find the in which field u getting this issue, so dont activate the feature at that time of feature deployment. manually activate the feature and debug it. then post ur field definition over here.may be ur field have null value not sure about it..

Answer (score 0):

Try Boolean with a capital B so your Field element (inside of the MetaData element) would be like:

```
<Field Name="MyBool" 
       ID="{some-guid}" 
       DisplayName="My Bool" 
       Description="The big ol' bool."
       Type="Boolean"/>
```

You can also try to specify the SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" but that shouldn't be necessary I don't think.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I found four instances where `Type="boolean"` and changed them to `Type="Boolean"`.  I also added `SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"` to my `Field` elements.  Now my deployment attempts just have `Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features':` with no further details.